# I need an elegant way to exclude specific words from processing

Tags: java, algorithm, file-io

I am writing an algorithm to extract likely keywords from a document's text. I want to count instances of words and take the top 5 as keywords. Obviously, I want to exclude "insignificant" words lest every document appears with "the" and "and" as major keywords.

Here is the strategy I've successfully used for testing:

```
exclusions = new ArrayList<String>();
exclusions.add("a","and","the","or");
```

Now that I want to do a real-life test, my exclusion list is close to 200 words long, and I'd LOVE to be able to do something like this:

```
exclusions = new ArrayList<String>();
exclusions.add(each word in foo.txt);
```

Long term, maintaining an external list (rather than a list embedded in my code) is desirable for obvious reasons. With all the file read/write methods out there in Java, I'm fairly certain that this can be done, but my search results have come up empty...I know I've got to be searching on the wrong keywords. Anyone know an elegant way to include an external list in processing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `FileReader` to read the `String`s out of the file and add them to an `ArrayList`.

```
private List<String> createExculsions(String file) throws IOException {
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
   String word = null;
   List<String> exclusions = new ArrayList<String>();

   while((word = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      exclusions.add(word);
   }

   return exclusions;
}
```

Then you can use `List<String> exclusions = createExclusions("exclusions.txt");` to create the list.

Answer (score 1):

This does not immediately address the solution you are prescribing but might give you another avenue that might be better.

Instead of deciding in advance what is useless, you could count everything and then filter out what you deem is insignificant (from a information carrying standpoint) because of its overwhelming presence. It is similar to a [low-pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) in signal processing to eliminate noise.

So in short, count everything. Then decide that if something appears with a frequency higher than a threshold you set (you'll have to determine what that threshold is from experiment, say 5% of all words are 'the', that means it does not carry information).

If you do it this way, it'll even work for foreign languages.

Just my two cents on this.

Answer (score 0):

Google Guava library contains lots of useful methods that simplify routine tasks. You can use one of them to read file contents to string and split it by space character:

```
String contents = Files.toString(new File("foo.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
List<String> exclusions = Lists.newArrayList(contents.split("\\s"));
```

Apache Commons IO provides similar shortcuts:

```
String contents = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("foo.txt"));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is elegant but here I created a simple solution to detect the language or remove noise words from tweets some years ago:

- [TweetDetector.java](https://github.com/karussell/Jetwick/blob/master/src/main/java/de/jetwick/tw/TweetDetector.java)
- [JTweet.java](https://github.com/karussell/Jetwick/blob/master/src/main/java/de/jetwick/data/JTweet.java) which is using the data like for [english](https://github.com/karussell/Jetwick/blob/master/src/main/java/de/jetwick/data/noise_words_en.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Commons-io has utilities that support this. Include commons-io as a dependency, then issue

```
File myFile = ...;
List<String> exclusions = FileUtils.readLines( myFile );
```

as described in:
http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

This assumes that every exclusion word is on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from a file is pretty simple.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class ExcludeExample {
    public static HashSet<String> readExclusions(File file) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = "";
        HashSet<String> exclusions = new HashSet<String>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            exclusions.add(line);
        }
        br.close();
        return exclusions;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        File foo = new File("foo.txt");
        HashSet<String> exclusions = readExclusions(foo);
        System.out.println(exclusions.contains("the"));
        System.out.println(exclusions.contains("Java"));
    }
}
```

foo.txt

```
the
a
and
or
```

I used a HashSet instead of a ArrayList because it has faster lookup.

Comment: I'll preface by saying file operations are the rustiest part of Java for me. A couple ?s: in HashSet<String>, does filename refer to the literal value of my exclusion list? or is this a variable I'm not seeing set or passed from somewhere? And, wouldn't  File foo=new File("foo.txt") create a new, blank foo.txt for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: new File("foo.txt") creates a file Object referring to the file "foo.txt". It doesn't open the file, the file is opened by the FileReader passed to the BufferedReader. Best way to see what does what is to copy the code and try it out, the code should be fully working.

I changed the variable name filename to file because it is more accurate.